# How to wire a 12V double solenoid to an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have recently been trying to pneumatically actuate a cylinder using a 12 V double solenoid and an Arduino Uno. The solenoid works when tested without code and wiring, however when I try to actuate the cylinder using code, nothing happens. I have a feeling that the way in which I wired everything to the breadboard may be incorrect, so I was wondering if anyone had any tips or good schematics by which I could wire it all together.

The materials I am using are two PNP transistors, two resistors, two diodes, and then the actual solenoid and similar hardware. My code is just a simple LED blink code which can be used to send signals to the solenoids, so I do not believe that is the issue. However, I have attached it underneath just in case.

```
int solenoid1 = 4;
int solenoid2 = 5;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(solenoid1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(solenoid2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(solenoid1, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(solenoid1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(solenoid2, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(solenoid2, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arduino digital pin puts 5V when HIGH. So your 12V solenoid do not get enough voltage to run. You have to use relay and additional 12V power supply to run your solenoid with Arduino.

Comment: I put in two 9 V batteries as well, and they managed to turn the light in the solenoid on as well, but the code which I have written is not running when the Arduino gets plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

> The code which I have written is not running when the Arduino gets plugged in

How can you see this?

A solenoid certainly cannot be controlled by 5V * 20mA from an Arduino pin. Further requirements depend on the solenoid you want to use. (Current consumption, free-wheeling diode already integrated?)